# How to fix hdfs append excepiton:already the current lease holder

Tags: java, scala, hdfs

I pull data from kafka,and append data to HDFS.But I got exception message when append data.

here is exception message

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Failed to APPEND_FILE T_LOG_RECORD_CS/web-Thread-3 for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-558981961_18 on IP地址 because DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-558981961_18 is already the current lease holder.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2970)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2766)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:3073)
        at ...
com.sharing.hdfs.HdfsHelper$.getFSDataOutputSteam(HdfsHelper.scala:225)
        at com.sharing.hdfs.HdfsHelper$.writeLines(HdfsHelper.scala:149)
```

this is my code,I use writeLines method to append datas to HDFS.

```
/**
    * 创建fsDataOutputSteam
    *
    * @param path
    * @return
    */
  def getFSDataOutputSteam(path: String): FSDataOutputStream = {
    val pathIsExist = isExist(path)
    if (pathIsExist) {
      fileSystem.append(path)
    } else {
      fileSystem.create(path)
    }
  }

// 写入数据
def writeLines(lines: java.util.List[String], path: String): Unit = {


    var outputStream: FSDataOutputStream = null
    try {

      outputStream = getFSDataOutputSteam(path)
      lines.foreach({
        line =>
          outputStream.write(line.trim.getBytes("UTF-8"))
          outputStream.write("\n".getBytes("UTF-8"))
      })
      LOGGER.info("HDFS写入成功！")
    }
    catch {
      case e: IOException =>
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage, e)
        updateLease(path)
        throw new IOException(e)
    } finally {
      if (Objects.nonNull(outputStream)) {
        outputStream.close()
      }
    }
  }
```

Please give me some help！Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

When you create your FileSystem, more exactly the Configuration Class, add the flowing property setting:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", HDFS_PATH);
conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
conf.set("dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy", "NEVER");
conf.set("dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.enable", "true");
```